# Dystonic Reaction and acute kidney failure

Tags: kidney, correlation, antipsychotic

Dystonic reactions seem to be a common reaction on a lot of the antipsychotic drugs.

Also kidney failure.  Are these issues related in any way?

Comment: Because two things occur together doesn't mean that they are related.  What evidence makes you think apart from frequency that they are?